# My PS3 controller malfunctions when I connect it to my laptop

Tags: 14.04, steam, ps3

I've been using a PS3 controller (USB) on my desktop on Ubuntu without any modifications or additional packages, and assigned it with Steam. It is working fine. However on my Laptop (an ASUS X551CA to be exact) it appears not to be working alright. Each time I connect it, it seems to rapidly spam the R1 button, making it unusable on crucial games.

I am entirely sure that this is not a hardware conflict as this controller works fine on Ubuntu on my desktop, on Windows and I also checked with a PS3 system.

I'm not sure if this might be a package conflict, but there are too many packages I can check on...

Can anyone help?
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr

Comment: Edit: using jstest-gtk the R1 button appears to be fine, but within Steam I still have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved by reinstalling Steam: Steam conflicted with controller input and after reinstalling this it works fine.